# Не cрабатывает в css "background-image"

Tags: css

Помогите пожалуйста, почему фоновое изображение не появляется? Если просто как картинку вставить в HTML - то всё в порядке, а как фоновое изображение ну никак..Пол дня кручусь.. что не так может быть? Заранее спасибо

```
body { 
width: 100%; 
background-image: url('\C:\Users\Asus 201\Desktop\курс основы программирования\дидим2.jpg');

    }
```

Comment: путь укажите относительный.

Comment: как вам курс? планируете с geekbrains сотрудничать?

Comment: Важно понимать, что `url` резольвится в браузере, который про файловую систему на сервере не может ничего знать. В `css` нужны рабочие ссылки, такие, по которым вы можете открыть картинку в соседней вкладке. `/images/1.jpg`, `/1.jpg`, `http://images.ru/cool.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

путь указывайте относительно файла css, в котором это прописано.
Если хотите выйти на папку вверх то используйте `../`, а потом уже путь к картинке
[Подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83)

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, получилось!

Answer (score 2):

неверно указан адрес

C:/Users/Asus 201/Desktop/курс основы программирования/дидим2.jpg

или

C:\\Users\Asus 201\\Desktop\\курс основы программирования\\дидим2.jpg